# package install carousel_pro 1.0.0 in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-web

**some one solve this issue**
Running "flutter pub get" in owels_ford...
Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.

╷

21 │ ┌     sdk: flutter

22 │ │     carousel_pro: ^0.0.13

23 │ │

24 │ │   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

25 │ │   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

26 │ │   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

│ └──^

╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
Process finished with exit code 65

Comment: spacing is important, make carousel_pro in line of flutter just above sdk: flutter line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spacing is highly important in pubspec.yaml file you have to just give one tab and there you have to add package.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_pro: ^0.0.13
```

look carousel_pro: ^0.0.13 is starting in line of flutter.

Comment: It's good working

Answer (score 0):

make sure the second line of the dependency is slightly to the right